# How to install an application signing certificate on a Motorola Phone?

Tags: java-me, certificate, sign

Motorola phones do not have Verisign/Thawte root certificates for code signing. They only embed Java UTI certificate, that requires you to pay to sign your application for every phone model you want to sign the app for (and this, every time you want a new version of the app).

I've created a simple web page pointing to a certificate (DER format) to check if the certificate can be installed.

On Nokia phones, it works ok. On Motorola, the phone says "unknown file format".

Is there a way to make this work? The file has an ".cer" extension, is it wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What specific phones are you targetting?

Comment: Any Motorola Phone (all phones, if possible).
The app is already signed with a Thawte/Verisign certificate and works ok on Nokia and Sony phones. Motorola does not have the root Thawte certificate for code signing, so what i'm trying to do is to install that certificate so the phone believes the app.
If at all possible, i would like this install to be via an URL (i would like not to have to plug the phone into an USB port on the computer).
Thanks for the interest you took on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last time I had to do something like that, I'm afraid that required getting Motorola itslef to sign the application.
That was before the Motorola mobile division current issues, though.
Hopefully, this is still possible.